# VSCode php-swagger 3.0 annotation plugins?

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, annotations, openapi, swagger-3.0

Does there is php-swagger annotation plugins in VSCode?
I write the annotation recently, but there is some inconvenience while the indent is not automatic or the keyword can not be auto-complete.

Or do anyone suggest another ide with this plugin?

Comment: I'm also hoping to find a plugin that adds some IDE feedback while writing swagger annotations. I tend to flip-flop between PHP Storm and VS Code. I prefer VS Code but there's always something I can't get to work. PHP Storm has a plugin called "PHP Annotations" and it works great for swagger-php.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using Swagger-PHP Annotation:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qvtec3.swagger-php-annotation

See on github: https://github.com/qvtec/swagger-php-annotation